# PHP prepare data for dynamic google stacked Chart

Tags: php

I need to display a google stacked bar chart grouped by month.

The data I fetched from database have following structure

```
['2017-08', 2, 'Value1' ],
['2017-08', 1, 'Value2' ],
['2017-08', 3, 'Value3' ],
['2017-08', 5, 'Value4' ],
['2017-10', 2, 'Value1' ],
['2018-02', 2, 'Value2' ],
['2018-02', 4, 'Value1' ],
['2018-02', 5, 'Value3' ],
```

What i need is this format:

```
   ['2017-08', 2, 1, 3, 5],
   ['2018-02', 2, 4, 5],
```

**Question 1:**

How can i create an array (i think that is the best way to handle this?!) **based on the month** and push the elements.

**Question 2:**

I need also the values / legends as corresponding rows in google charts. If i use a foreach and echo the values, there are some duplicates.

Comment: What about 2017-10 ?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to do some processing before you can pass the data in the format Google Chart wants it.

```
$data = [
['2017-08', 2, 'Value1' ],
['2017-08', 1, 'Value2' ],
['2017-08', 3, 'Value3' ],
['2017-08', 5, 'Value4' ],
['2017-10', 2, 'Value1' ],
['2018-02', 2, 'Value2' ],
['2018-02', 4, 'Value1' ],
['2018-02', 5, 'Value3' ]
]  ;

$googleChartArray = array(); //Use this array to group the results using date.
foreach( $data as $d ) {
    $date = $d[0];
    $value = $d[1];
    if( !isset( $googleChartArray[$date] ) ) {
        $googleChartArray[$date] = array( "'". $date. "'" ); //Date needs to be enclosed in quote.
    }
    $googleChartArray[$date][] = $value;
}

$f = array(); //Format the above array to split value in a comma separated format.
foreach( $googleChartArray as $g ) {
    $f[] = implode( ',' , $g );
}
```

Comment: The problem is, that the array have different numbers from counts/values. So i get this error Uncaught (in promise) Error: Row given with size different than 3 (the number of columns in the table)